# Solve for $b$ in $(\frac{1}{a} + b(\frac{n}{1/a})^{\frac{1}{b}}) * log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) = \frac{1}{a}log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) * log_2(n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need to get $b$ from
$$(\frac{1}{a} + b(\frac{n}{1/a})^{\frac{1}{b}}) \times log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) = \frac{1}{a}log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) \times log_2(n)$$

and values for $b$ for $$(\frac{1}{a} + b(\frac{n}{1/a})^{\frac{1}{b}}) \times log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) < \frac{1}{a}log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) \times log_2(n)$$

So far I have:

$$b(\frac{n}{1/a})^{\frac{1}{b}} \times log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) = \frac{1}{a}log_2({\frac{1}{\delta}}) \times (log_2(n) - 1)$$

$$b(\frac{n}{1/a})^{\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{1}{a} (log_2(n) - 1)$$

and now I am stuck because I do not know how to get $b$ out of this...

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write your last equation as $$b A^b=B$$ The solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$b=\frac{W(B \log (A))}{\log (A)}$$ In fact, any equation which write or rewrite in the form $A+B x+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has analytical solutions expressed in terms of Lambert function.

The Wikipedia page gives formulae for approximating $W(z)$.

If you do not want to use Lambert function, only numerical methods will work. For example Newton applied to equation $$f(b)=\log(b)+b \log(A)-\log(B)$$ will work very well. Faster woulf be the convergence of Halley method which has been extensively used by Corless (references in the Wikipedia page).